# Android - map: getValue from key with whitespaces

Tags: android, hashmap, whitespace

I have a map `<String, Float>`. The keys contains a whitespaces after the correct value, at the end of the string. So when I use

```
Object value = dd.get("22 ");
```

or

```
value = dd.get("22");
```

with space or without it returns null. And if i use

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), value.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

it crashes my app because the value is null.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following example, just to show you that the problem are not any whitespaces:

```
Map<String, Float> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("1", 1f);
myMap.put("1 ", 2f);

Float f1 = myMap.get("1"); // f1: 1.0
Float f2 = myMap.get("1 "); // f2: 2.0
```

As expected, i don´t get any null values. So the problem must be somewhere else. My guess: your requested value is not present in your map.

To prevent your app from crashing, i would suggest you to check if the value is null and if so, replace it with some other value.

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), value == null ? "-" : value.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: i have solved changing the input from backend in order to remove the whitaspaces